# Why is this question locked from recieving upvotes?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderation

[How is color determined when colorizing black and white movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/how-is-color-determined-when-colorizing-black-and-white-movies)

This post is locked and is not allowing up votes while the answers do? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written in the description, the question was locked due to a content dispute. Specifically, the asker kept repeatedly readding invalid tags to the question.

Comment: Can it be unlocked? I will not edit it any more.

Comment: It has been unlocked.

Comment: thanks you very much!!!!

Comment: In general, these locks are usually only temporary and it might have been auto-unlocked after a week anyway.